# Git config "bad config file line" in a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-config

I use git on Windows and Linux, and I have recently ran into a strange issue that manifests only on Windows... Let's say I have two projects. Both are versioned in git, and each has a submodule.

---

## Project 1

the submodule config is located in `C:\Projects\project1\.git\modules\plugins\tasks\config` and looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    worktree = ..\..\..\..\plugins\tasks
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://domain/repo/path
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

---

## Project 2

The submodule configuration is located in `C:\Projects\project2\.git\modules\doc\preamble\config`, and I also provide it below:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    worktree = ../../../../doc/preamble
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://domain/another/repo/path
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

---

To sum up, the only real difference between the configuration files is the `/` and `\` in paths to working directory.

---

## Issue

I operate in Git Bash. When I do `git status` (and some other simple commands) in **Project 1** and its submodule:

```
/c/Projects/project1 (devel) $ git status
fatal: bad config file line 6 in c:/Projects/project1/.git/modules/plugins/tasks/config
fatal: 'git status --porcelain' failed in submodule plugins/tasks

/c/Projects/project1/plugins/tasks $ git status
fatal: bad config file line 6 in d:/Projects/project1/.git/modules/plugins/tasks/config

/c/Projects/project1 (devel) $ git submodule sync -- plugins/tasks/
Synchronizing submodule url for 'plugins/tasks'
fatal: bad config file line 6 in c:/Projects/project1/.git/modules/plugins/tasks/config
```

Also, `git submodule init` or `update` or `update --init` give no output, and don't improve the situation.

While, when I use `git` in **Project 2**, everything is ok.

You'd think that the naive solution is to substitute the slashes in the submodule config by hand, more elaborate solution would be to write a script that does that in all affected submodules.

Unfortunately, actually, changing the path in 1st config from:

```
worktree = ..\..\..\..\plugins\tasks
```

to:

```
worktree = ../../../../plugins/tasks
```

results in a different error:

```
/c/Projects/project1/plugins/tasks $ git status
fatal: bad object HEAD
```

and when I look into the file `c/Projects/project1/.git/modules/plugins/tasks/refs/master` something is wrong there, as the SHA1 inside is:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

At this point, after I did `git reset --hard origin/master` (in the submodule) the repository of the submodule was restored to usable state.

**But, what went wrong there in the first place?**

If possible, I would like to know why did this issue even occur? Does this have anything to do with the original platform of the project? Does it matter how I initialize the submodule? I would like to track down the reason of the issue to avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Despite being in Windows, `git` thinks like a UNIX program so forward slashes are the right thing.  See http://gitbyexample.org/ for some examples of using forward slashes in Windows `git`.
2. Something is broke in your repo.  I'm not sure what, but before fighting with it too much, can you reclone?  Rename the old top directory from `project1` to `project1.fubar` and redo `git clone foo://project1` and your directories should
   end up correct.